# How do I get XML data out of SQL Server 2005 and insert it as a node into a TXMLDocument?

Tags: xml, delphi

I need to get data out of my database to create individual xml files. I've got most of it done, but I don't know how to get the data out of the XML field and into the XMLDocument I'm creating. When I try to do it as text, it doesn't work right.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
XMLDoc.Active := true;
aNode := XMLDoc.AddChild('item');
aNode.SetAttribute('id','Drug');
bNode := aNode.AddChild('item');
bNode.SetAttribute('id','LDPId');
bNode.Text := IntToStr(vwFirstLifeLabelId.Value); // This works fine.

bNode := aNode.AddChild('item');
bNode.SetAttribute('id','Indications and Usage');
bNode.Text := vwFirstLifeIndicationsandUsage.AsString; // This doesn't work!
```

**What I get in the xml is:**

```
<item id="Drug">
<item id="LDPId">38696</item>
<item id="Warnings and Precautions">?&lt;component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"&gt;&lt;section ID="Section_5"&gt;&lt;id root="2e0bdeb7-2254-4217-b6b6-523848d65112"/&gt &lt/section&gt;&lt;/component&gt;</item>
</item>
```

**Instead of:**

```
<item id="Drug">
<item id="LDPId">38696</item>
<item id="Warnings and Precautions">
<component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<section ID="Section_5">
<id root="2e0bdeb7-2254-4217-b6b6-523848d65112"/>
</section>
</component>
</item>
</item>
```

I guess I have two questions: 1) How do I get the XML out of the xmlfield as XML and not as text, and 2) How do I then insert a section of XML as a child under my Warnings and Precautions node?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer me!

Terry

Answer (score 3):

if i understand correctly your question, you need read  XML string from a field and insert into a Xml Node. you can do this creating a *Dummy* Xml Document and load the Xml string, then retrieve the  `DocumentElement` property and assign to the Node which you want.

check this sample

```
const
 XmlStr =
  '<component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">'+
  '<section ID="Section_5">'+
  '<id root="2e0bdeb7-2254-4217-b6b6-523848d65112"/>'+
  '</section>'+
  '</component>';
var
  oXmlDoc  : IXMLDocument;
  cXmlDoc  : IXMLDocument;
  Node     : IXMLNode;
begin
  oXmlDoc         := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
     oXmlDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
     oXmlDoc.Active := true;
     Node:=oXmlDoc.AddChild('item');

         cXmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
         try
           cXmlDoc.Active := true;
           cXmlDoc.LoadFromXML(XmlStr);
           //assing the XML to the Node
           Node.ChildNodes.Add(cXmlDoc.DocumentElement);
         finally
           cXmlDoc:=nil;
         end;

  finally
     oXmlDoc:=nil;
  end;
end;
```

the result will be

```
<item>
  <component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <section ID="Section_5">
      <id root="2e0bdeb7-2254-4217-b6b6-523848d65112"/>
    </section>
  </component>
</item>
```